# Gnome-terminal overwriting/ignoring manual file changes to .gconf xml profiles

Tags: ubuntu, profile, gnome-terminal, gconf

I have an XML file for a custom profile for gnome-terminal.  However, when I throw the file into an appropriate directory like ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml the file is clobbered the next time I run gnome-terminal.  The problem happens also if I make a  new profile and manually copy my xml file over the newly created profile's xml.  It also happens if I perform the copy actions when gnome-terminal is not running (I log into one of the psuedo-consoles and thus can't be running gnome-terminal).  No matter what happens, the next time I run gnome-terminal, the profile colors aren't applied, and the %gconf.xml file that I had edited is changed to the contents of the default profile (as I said, clobbered).

I'm running ubuntu 10.04 with the gnome desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `gnome-terminal`'s fault; it's merely talking to the `gconfd` daemon which has its own view of your configuration, which (aside from reading upon startup) doesn't care what happens to the files on disk.

Instead of editing the XML directly, how about using [gconftool-2](http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/) or some other official mechanism, instead of going around `gconfd`'s back?

If that's too difficult for you, it may be possible to `gconftool-2 --shutdown` to signal `gconfd` to exit, make the changes, then `gconftool-2 --spawn` to restart `gconfd`.  However, other processes using GSettings or GConf may respawn `gconfd` before you are done.

Comment: That helps a lot.  It makes tracking configurations for half of ubuntu a PITA (well, not tracking, but *recovery*), but I'll just convert my configs into gconftool scripts.

Comment: After looking at the documentation, I have to question is this actually constitutes a "GOOD REASON" for using `--shutdown`.